# ASP.MVC Bundles - how to define them correctly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have something like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Styles/Default/Forums").Include("~/Content/Styles/Default/Forums/Main.css",
                                                                           "~/Content/Styles/Default/Forums/Slider.css"));
```

Now, when i release my application and run it, it creates a link like this:

```
<link href="/Content/Styles/Default/Forums?v=8vn0bgRpB8BncmaT_onrpNlXa4t9ydK6_Fep81xhhm01" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Which refers to my site directory, and access to that is disabled. But ASP doesn't let me specify files outside of the application, then how can I do it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The virtual path in the `StyleBundle` constructor doesn't have to match an existing path in your application:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
  "~/Content/Styles/Default/Forums/Main.css",
  "~/Content/Styles/Default/Forums/Slider.css"));
```

If you want to use external files, you can use the CDN path on the bundle (you need to set the `UseCDN` property to `true`):

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css", "<CDN Path>").Include(
  "<CDN Path>/Main.css",
  "<CDN Path>/Slider.css"));
```

Comment: `The virtual path in the StyleBundle constructor doesn't have to match an existing path in your application:` What do you mean by that?

Comment: I my example, I use `new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")`, but there is no such virtual directory. Of course, in your view, you have to use `RenderStyle("~/Content/css")`.